# We're trying to build a simple OptaPlanner solution for an animal shelter and it's only marginally working

Tags: optaplanner

We're trying to make an OptaPlanner solution for an animal shelter so that their staff can spend their time with the animals instead of trying to schedule everything manually.  However, despite our solution being fairly simple so far, it doesn't seem to be able to solve even basic tests.  We only have about 5 constraints.  I've tried to change the heuristic algorithm and some other things, but no dice.  Does anybody have any resources such as what to try if one's OptaPlanner solution doesn't work?
Thanks.

Comment: What example did you base it from? If it involves time, is it a time grain or chained through time pattern (see docs chapter 22).

Comment: Hi Geoffrey, it's a chained through time pattern.  I've set up the benchmarking but I have some exceptions to work through.

Comment: I was able to fix the exceptions, and benchmarking runs, but seems there's a problem with the model.  I will add comments to your answer below.

Comment: Try enviromnentMode FULL_ASSERT (slows things down but flushes out any corruption with a clearer point to where it's being corupted)

Answer (score 0):

The `optaplanner-benchmark` is usually a good way to help figure out why a problem doesn't get solved well and if it scales well. It shows **the best score graph** and your **score calculation speed**.

If it's a big enough dataset, this should help, if you compare your best score graph to it:

[image]

If your score calculation speed is below 1000, that's bad.

Comment: Thank-you, Geoffrey, I will try this.

Comment: So I did get benchmarking set up, and it runs.  All tests fail, but I think the most important thing is the exceptions that print.  They seem to show problems with our model:

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org..PlannerBenchmarkException: Benchmarking failed: failureCount (5). The exception of the firstFailureSingleBenchmarkRunner (Test.test1_First Fit_0) is chained.


Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot use class (..Room) in a constraint stream as it is neither the same as, nor a superclass or superinterface of one of planning entities or problem facts.
Ensure that all from(),...only reference classes assignable from planning entities or problem facts ([..Animal, ..ShelterConstraintConfig]) annotated on the planning solution (..ShelterSolution).

Comment: Hi Geoffrey, we are still stumped.  We can't even solve the most basic test.  I'm wondering if you would be so kind as to look at our solution - we trimmed it down to the most basic functionality and perhaps if you looked at it you could quickly tell us what we're doing wrong.  If you are willing, how would you like me to send you a zip of our application?  Thanks so much.

Comment: Hi again, Geoffrey: good news, we managed to get one test working for Tabu algorithm.  4 other heuristic algorithms do not work at the moment, but we'll keep trying.

Comment: That's very weird and unusual. A deep diagnostic should reveal the cause. Think enviromnentMode FULL_ASSERT, score calculation speed > 1000, CPU profiling, ...